# Vuex $store.watch add and remove eventListener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here's my store watcher in a `mounted()`:

```
  this.$store.watch(
    (state, getters) => state.windowState && state.chatState == 0,
    (val, oldVal) => {
      if (val) {
        console.log('state is true')
        this.$refs.chatAuth.addEventListener('keydown', this.pressEnterChatAuth)
      } else {
        console.log('state is false')
        this.$refs.chatAuth = null
      }
    }
  )
```

`windowState` - is a bool value,
`chatState` - is a Number value, like 0, 1, 2

In my case, if `windowState` becomes `true` and `chatState` becomes 1, my eventlistener is still alive, it's not removed. Can't figure out. Is it possible to `$store.watch` 2 states or getters at the same time?

In case, where `chatState` is 1, i'm getting console message "state is false", but listener is still here, omg.

**My thoughts**

I suspect when a watched value returns false, `this.$refs.chatAuth` already removed from the DOM, because it's conditionally rendered, depending on `chatState`, so my `else` block is executed, but setting `null` on non existing element has no effect, because it's already been removed from the DOM, but if it's already removed, then why listener is still working?

Comment: `$refs` are read only property and not reactive. What do you expect from this line `this.$refs.chatAuth = null`?

Comment: @MaxSinev, i expect to remove a reference to this element with event listener, because even if console shows a false message, i still have this listener, though this element is removed from the DOM, with `v-if`

Comment: you want to hide/remove element from DOM or just want to remove event listener?

Comment: I just want to remove event listener. Paraphrase, why my eventlistener is not being removed? I even tried `removeEventlistener` before setting it to `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using Vue native event listeners:

```
<div @keydown.enter.exact="pressEnterChatAuth" class="chat__auth"></div>
```

That was so obvious, lol. No need to hassle with `addEventListener`.